# Difference between simultaneous and ordered N.E. in the problem.

Tags: solution-verification, game-theory, nash-equilibrium

Consider the following game. There are two players and one of them could be in two states:
$A$ with probability $p$ and $B$ with probability $1 - p$. Both players actions are $1, 2,$ and to not participate.

If the state is $A$ then players get $\$1$ if 1 is majority action, 1/2 if they tie, and 0 if 2 is the majority. Likewise, we determine the game in the state $B$.

Now we have a question to find Bayes-Nash equilibrium (pure) in two situations: (1) simultaneous game and (2) first go first, and then second take part.

I've decided that in first case we have: N.E. not participate for first player and $(1 , 2)$ (say $1$ in situation $A$ and say $2$ in situation $B$). However I've got the same for simultaneous game. There is a problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your description of the game is a bit vague, so I have to make a few assumptions. First, you say "Likewise, we determine the game in the state $B$." I am assuming here the payoffs are flipped (payoff of 1 iff both choose "2"), otherwise payoffs would be state independent and there is no point in using Bayes Nash equilibrium.

Second, in the sequential game, I assume the actions of the first moving player is observable for the second (otherwise it would be equivalent to a simultaneous move game).

Third, you say "one of them could be in two states". It can make a difference which player observes those states and which player moves first in the sequential game. Suppose player 2 is the one who privately observes the state, but player 1 doesn't, and player 2 moves second. Then this situation is identical to the simultaneous move game. However, if player 1 were to move second, then it changes things, because the action of player 2 could then "reveal" the state to the other player.

Regarding equilibrium: You are right that the informed player choosing $(1,2)$ and the uninformed choosing "no participation" is a BNE. Any deviation by the informed player would strictly reduce his payoff, given the uninformed player abstains. And a deviation by the uninformed player cannot improve things but can decrease his payoff (if the incorrect action is chosen which does not match the state). You are also right that in the sequential game this is a BNE as well - after all, both players get the maximum payoff in every state with probability 1, so there is no way to improve on this.

There are additional equilibria in some cases. For example, in the sequential game, if player 1 moves first and is informed, then the following strategy is also a BNE: $(1,2)$ for player 1 and for player 2: 1 if first player chose 1 and 2 if first player chose 2. The outcomes in this equilibrium are the same, however, the uninformed player does not actually abstain. This equilibrium does not exist if the order of moves is reversed; this is why I pointed out above it might matter.

Comment: Nice work in approaching a Question that (probably unintentionally) leaves out many crucial elements of the setup.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! In my problem first player is informed about state of the second one. And in sequential game player 1 goes first. Also, I've got quite opposite: first player should take n.p. in both states and (1,2) for the second one.That's not right?

Comment: And that's nice idea about repetition the action! If the first player choose $1$, then logically it should be state $A$ and it's better to repeat his action.

Comment: If the second player does not observe whether the state is $A$ or $B$, then how can his action react to the realization of the state? It cannot. So whichever player knows whether the state is $A$ or $B$, that player's actions should react to the state.

Comment: So the situation should be the opposite? $((1,2), n.p.)$  in the simultaneous game, and the second player should participate? Then how it differs from sequential game?

Comment: Your description above is not clear enough that I can give you a clear answer. I can only repeat my previous statement: Whichever player knows whether the state is $A$ or $B$, that player's action should be reacting to the state. The other player obviously cannot do this, because he does not observe/know whether the state is $A$ or $B$, and hence, whether he should be playing 1 or 2. You know your setting best, does player 1 or player 2 know whether $A$ or $B$ realized?

Comment: Player 1 is informed and player 2 just tried to guess his states. And evaluate it as $A$ with probability $p$ and $1 - p$ to $B$.

Comment: Then player 2 (uninformd) must be the one choosing not to participate, and player 1 (informed) chooses 1 or 2 depending on the state. Wouldn't work the other way around. This is true for both the simultaneous and the sequential game. As pointed out, in the sequential game you have an additional equilibrium where the second player reacts to the first.